# How to automatically leverage hypotheses of the form x <> y?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

```
Goal forall (w x y z: string), w <> x -> (if (eqb_string w x) then y else z) = z.
Proof.
  intros.
  rewrite false_eqb_string by trivial.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

`false_eqb_string` is a rather trivial proof principle. I'd like to use it implicitly, via `autorewrite` or similar. Unfortunately, if I add `Hint Rewrite false_eqb_string`, then any subterm of the form `eqb_string _ _` gets rewritten, and the assumption `_ <> _` added to goals, even when that's not a sensible thing to do.

How can I make `rewrite false_eqb_string by trivial` happen automatically, without mentioning it by name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the construction you are looking for is

```
Hint Rewrite false_eqb_string using solve [ trivial ].
```

This is documented in [the reference manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:cmd.hint-rewrite).  Unlike `rewrite ... by ...`, `Hint Rewrite ... using ...` will not undo the rewrite if the tactic does not fully solve the side conditions, so you must wrap it in `solve [ ... ]` to get that effect.

Answer (score 2):

One fairly general construct is `match goal with`, allowing you to pattern-match on, well, your goal. So you can look for disequalities in your hypotheses with corresponding boolean comparisons in the goal (or other hypotheses if you want) (`context _ [ _ ]` is a special pattern that allows you to match any subterm against the pattern in brackets), and rewrite using the right lemma. You can then give this `match` tactic a name, so you don't need to remember how the lemma is actually called. As you might expect, `match` also supports many clauses (with a weird backtracking behavior to be aware of), so you can extend this tactic into your own poor man's rewriting database.

```
From Coq Require Import Arith.

Ltac rewrite_eqb :=
  match goal with
  | [ H : ?u <> ?v |- context E [ ?u =? ?v ] ] =>
    rewrite (proj2 (Nat.eqb_neq u v) H)
  end.

Goal forall (w x y z: nat), w <> x -> (if (Nat.eqb w x) then y else z) = z.
Proof.
  intros.
  rewrite_eqb.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

See also:

- [The Tactic language: matching on goals](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#pattern-matching-on-goals) in the Reference manual;
- Some chapter in CPDT (probably).